# How to find the status of automated builds in Docker Hub

Tags: dockerhub

How to find the status of automated builds which get triggered either manually or via the Trigger url for a Docker Hub project.

```
https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/company/webapp/builds
```

1. I would like to understand if its running and if its running the current status (i.e still running or build completed)
2. List of past builds
3. Status of all builds (time initiated, completed, build status)

Comment: It does not look like build status is available in the dockerhub API

Comment: Looks like, its important information to have in order to check the status

Comment: It seems you can add hooks to your application and collect the information in your application. A possible solution...
https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/advanced/#custom-build-phase-hooks

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
curl https://hub.docker.com/api/build/v1/source/?image={namespace}/{repo} | jq '.objects[0].state'
```

Add bearer token in your request if it is a private repo

```
-H "Authorization: Bearer {Token}"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
docker ps --no-trunc
```

will display the list of full containers and builds and details of the other running containers.